# What's the name of the manga with a girl who has two bodyguards?

Tags: time-stranger-kyoko

It's a fantasy manga and there's a girl who has two bodyguards who may have been brothers. They spend all of their lives together and even sleep in the same bed.

But then one night one of the two bodyguards kisses the girl in her sleep (which is not allowed) and so one of them confesses and is going to be put to death or punished and it's all very sad until you find out the one who kissed her was actually the other bodyguard and that he knew the other guy would try to defend him and take the blame

I think the to guards are orphans, also there's some element of magic I think- demons may or may not be involved- I'm not 100% sure on that

Comment: I'm almost dead sure what manga you talk about. The girl is some kind of shaman from an old family. The bodyguards are shapeshifting dogs, one black, one white. The girl will go out at nights to hunt some kind of monsters with a katana and attends highschool. but sadly I can't seem to find it... Could you confirm or deny the details I put in here? If they match up I can say for sure that the manga is "finished" though.

Comment: hat sounds about right but I'm not sure if she really attended high school cause I dont think it took place during present day The manga is definitely completed though Thanks so much for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brother bodyguards sleeping in the same bed as a princess ?

It really sounds like [Time Stranger Kyoko](http://myanimelist.net/manga/86/Time_Stranger_Kyoko) (Arina Tanemura) to me

[image]

- Princess Kyoko shares her bed with two brothers guards

  > [image]
- She has a time base power
- It's about people having power like time, flower, dragon
- there are some demons too

  > she even actually has demon ears...
- the brothers are orphans
- She has been kissed by one of the brother but thought it was the other one,

  > then some revelations made the one who kissed her appart from them (so sad moment for them)
- She attends to high school, but not in our modern world, it is a mix-up between ancient/modern/fantasy/sf world
- BUT she doesn't use a katana but a talking staff

It's a bright, fun and adorable manga in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but it also kind of sounds like Heart no Diamond. It's about a girl who has a heart of a diamond and will hurt if anyone touches her. Then she befriends these two boys and they protect her when some body threatens to take her heart. You probably already found out what it was, so sorry that I'm late